# Meaning of theta notation in summation.

Tags: real-analysis, notation, asymptotics

Just a simple question: What does the big theta notation mean in this equation?

$$S(n,p) = \sum_i^ni^p=\Theta(n^{p+1})$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: thanks, was not sure what to search for on google.

Comment: You are very welcome. If there are some things left that are not clear after you read about the big theta notation in wikipedia, just edit your questoin and you will get an answer.

Comment: @5xum Thanks will do. Just started learning about algorithms in my free time(the Algorithm Design Manual by steven S. Skiena). Lots of interesting stuff to learn.